# Function prototype thinks a class type is undefined, although it's defined in the same header file

Tags: c++, class, prototype

It seems that the IF_ID_WRITE class object that is declared in main and defined in a header file is not recognized by a function prototype in the same header file.  When I move the prototype from Pipeline.h to Project.cpp, it compiles fine, but I don't want to resort to doing that.

What do I need to change to make it recognize the object type from Pipeline.h?

When I compile, I get the following three errors:
error C2065: 'IF_ID_WRITE' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'aIF_ID_WRITE' : undeclared identifier
error C2182: 'IF_stage' : illegal use of type 'void'

Pipeline.h file contains
    `#include <cstdlib>`
    `#include <iomanip>`
    `#include <iostream>`
    `using namespace std;`
    `#pragma once`

```
//function prototypes
void IF_stage(IF_ID_WRITE &aIF_ID_WRITE);

//IF_ID_WRITE defined
class IF_ID_WRITE {
private:
    int inst;
    int writeRegNum;
    int readReg1Num;
    int readReg2Num;
    int offset;
    int incrPC;
public:
    IF_ID_WRITE();
    void setWriteRegNum(int);
    void setReadReg1Num(int);
    void setReadReg2Num(int);
    ~IF_ID_WRITE()
};
```

Project.cpp contains
    `#include <cstdlib>`
    `#include <iomanip>`
    `#include <iostream>`
    `#include "Pipeline.h"`
    `using namespace std;`
    `#pragma once`

```
int main(){
.
.
.
IF_ID_WRITE aIF_ID_WRITE;      //creating an object called aIF_ID_WRITE of type IF_ID_WRITE
IF_stage(aIF_ID_WRITE);        //a function that will pass the object by reference
```

In the Pipeline.cpp file:
    `void IF_stage(IF_ID_WRITE& aIF_ID_WRITE)`
 
    `{`
    `//code`
    `}`

edited to show IF_ID_WRITE being defined in Pipeline.cpp

Comment: Where is `IF_ID_WRITE` declared? where is it defined?

Comment: There's no definition of the `IF_ID_WRITE` type in your `main`, just an instantiation for a variable of this type.

Comment: IF_ID_WRITE declared in Pipeline.h.  I'll edit the question to reflect that. Sorry

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I changed it to reflect IF_ID_WRITE being defined in Pipeline.h

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I forgot to show that in my question.  I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a top-down language, the type needs to be *declared* before you can declare a function that uses it. The compiler won't *look-ahead* to try to figure out whether `IF_ID_WRITE` exists later in the translation unit, it will just *fail* as it does not exist before the function declaration.

If you reorder the definition of the `IF_ID_WRITE` type and the function it should work. Since you are only declaring the function in the header, you can also provide a declaration of the type (no *definition* required) before the function declaration:

```
class IF_ID_WRITE;
void IF_stage(IF_ID_WRITE& aIF_ID_WRITE);
```

[There are other syntax issues, like the destructor missing `()`, but I *assume* this is an issue with the copy-paste into the question. I don't really believe this, but I'll skip the full code review]

Comment: Thanks!  Changing the order around did the trick.  The destructor () went missing in the copy paste.  I'll fix it though for anyone that might come along and look at it later.  Thanks again for the help!